# How to load a .msg file into pyspark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, outlook, rdd, azure-databricks

I am relatively new to pyspark programming, hence looking out for a way to read a bunch of outlook (.msg) files from databricks file system (dbfs). While executing the below line of code, I'm getting some junk unicode data as shown in output below:

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("dbfs:/......./*.msg")
```

Output:

```
[(u'dbfs:/........./file1.msg', u'\ufffd\ufffd\x11\u0871\x1a\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x03\x00\ufffd\ufffd\t\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd')]
```

Can anybody help me in implementing a pairedRDD wherein "key= path of email msg file" and "value= content of email msg file." ? Also, is there any alternative function that can be used to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

You should first convert(ETL) all the '.msg' format dataset to either some spark readable format like Avro, Parquet. Then read that in spark data frame.

Here is the pseudo code:

There is a python package to read *.msg files https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/

Use this package and get the **msg** object and get each attribute like below

```
import extract_msg
msg = extract_msg.Message("path/to/msg/file.msg")
msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
msg_sender = msg.sender
msg_date = msg.date
msg_subj = msg.subject
msg_message = msg.body
```

Then create a dataframe from **msg** and write that to parquet using fastparquet package

```
from fastparquet import write
write('outfile.parquet', msgDF)
```

Then reading the parquet file in pyspark

```
spark.read.parquet("outfile.parquet")
```